# Select By Location not working in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, select-by-location

I am attempting to perform a very simple "Select By Location" where I would like to select all the blue circles (buffers of x,y points) that "contain" brown boxes (stations), as per the image attached.

I opened the "Select By Location" tool, input the blue circles as the input features, the brown rectangles as the selecting features, and have tried relationships: "contains", "intersect", "completely contains".

The only way I have successfully produced a selection, is by instead selecting brown boxes within blue circles. This, however, is useless to me, I only tried to see if I could make any selection work. As it did, it suggests to me that there is something wrong with the relationships I am choosing paired with the feature types.

Why am I not getting the selection I expect?

[image]

Comment: What is your selection type set to?

Comment: It would help if you included the layer list from the TOC and a screenshot of your parameters.

Comment: Are all your data projected in the same coordinate system?

Comment: @Xeppit you were right! My CRS was not defined for the stations layer. Thank you!

Comment: You can self-answer the question and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a simple case of one of the layers not having a defined CRS. Defining the CRS of this layer caused "Select by Location" to work as expected.

Thanks @Xeppit for pointing it out.